# Force horizontal to incline plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

So I got this question ( part (ii) with figure 2) through searching the internet I think I found a way of doing it .
[image: question]

So I found the $x$ component of the weight of the block which is $9$N

$$9= \cos(30)P$$

And thus I got $P = 6\sqrt{3}$

Is this correct? And is there any other ways of arriving at this solution?

Comment: You're using $x$ axis as parallel to the incline?

Comment: Not correct. If the angle was 90, then would't P need to be 18 for part(i)? Sin(90) =1.  By parallel to the plane they mean the ramp.

Comment: @PhysicsDave, this is correct. OP is working on part ii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be a little more clear on your choice of coordinates. The answer you got out works, but it will benefit you in the future to work carefully! There are two natural choices for this problem. You can work with $x$ and $y$ or you can work with, let's call it $x'$ and $y'$ where $x'$ points down the ramp and $y'$ points normal to the ramp (from the bottom to the top of the block).

The force of gravity (call it $\vec{W}$) is $18$N in the $-y$ direction. There is the pushing force $\vec{P}$ which is in the $+x$ direction. There is also the normal force $\vec{N}$ which points in the $+y'$ direction. Before you can work out this problem, you need to break your vectors into components so that they are easy to add together. So you can choose to break $\vec{W}$ and $\vec{P}$ into their components along $x'$ and $y'$, or we can break $\vec{N}$ into its components along $x$ and $y$. Let's go with the former route since we know there's no acceleration in the $y'$ direction (i.e. it stays on the ramp).

So what's $\vec{N}$? Well it's whatever it needs to be to cancel the forces in the $y'$ direction.

Okay, so what's $\vec{W}$ in the $x',y'$ coordinate system? Here it helps to draw a triangle and clearly mark all the angles. If you do this you see that $W_{x'}= 18\cos(60°)\mbox{N}=9\mbox{N}$ and $W_{y'}=-18\sin(60°)\mbox{N}=-9\sqrt{3}\mbox{N}$ in the $x'$ direction.

How about $\vec{P}$?. You can see that the angle between $\vec{P}$ and the inclined plane is $30°$ so we find that $P_{x'}=-P\cos(30°)=-P\sqrt{3}/2$ and $P_{y'}=P\sin(30°)=P/2$.

Now armed with this information we can tackle the problem. We know the block doesn't move so adding all the forces in the $x'$ direction should give $0$ and adding all the forces in the $y'$ direction should give $0$. This tells us that $$P_{x'}+W_{x'}=0\to -P\sqrt{3}/2+9=0\to P=18/\sqrt{3}\mbox{N}=6\sqrt{3}\mbox{N}$$
You get this same answer by using the $x,y$ coordinates instead, see if you can get it to work!